# JavaScript does not sleep at the right position

Tags: javascript, sleep

I have a little problem. In my homepage i have a button. This Button calls a function up by onclick (onclick="showhidelogin()").

the function looks like this:

```
function showhidelogin() {
    document.getElementById("null").id = "menu-sticky";
    sleep(1000);
    document.getElementById("loginform").id = "loginformview";

}
```

Why did the page wait as first, and then execute the two "getElementById"-Statements?
(setTimeout does not work too)

Comment: There is no sleep function in `JavaScript`. Do you use any library?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `sleep` function in Javascript. You must do this using `setTimeout`.

```
function showhidelogin() {
    document.getElementById("null").id = "menu-sticky";
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("loginform").id = "loginformview";
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is not using setTimeout in the right way.. how can setTimeout not work?

Comment: Well our assumptions should be part of comments.. OP is not doing anything with the `DOM`, expected output seems different...

Comment: @Ananth Well, any function can be used such that it doesn't work in the expected way. For example OP might have `setTimeout = 'wtf'` at the top of his script. :)

Comment: Why OP is changing `id` property tho?

Answer (score 0):

**Improvement of Ananth's answer** (check if the `getElementById()` return something):

```
function showhidelogin() {
    if(document.getElementById("null")) {
        document.getElementById("null").id = "menu-sticky";
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (document.getElementById("loginform")) {
            document.getElementById("loginform").id = "loginformview";
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```